# Recycling the Application Pool creates 401 errors

Tags: iis-7, virtual-directory, url-rewrite-module

I am using the Rewrite Module on IIS 7.

When I restart the Application Pool I get a Authentication Required window that doesn't except any credentials that it is given and when you click cancel it goes to a 401 unauthorized page.

The rewrite rule sends the request to an ashx page in a virtual directory (_assets).

How can I resolve this strange behavior?

Anonymous is turned on and it works fine.

The following is the rewrite rule we are using:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Loader" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^[a-z0-9\-\/]*$" negate="false" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/_assets/includes/load.ashx?q={UrlEncode:{REQUEST_URI}}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I can get past the weird login by going to `/.reset`. This causes a 500 error and then the site is available again.

Note: Our application pools restart nightly.

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7786839/85371 and especially the linked [article by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) which points at [HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.registerobject.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I found a [forum post](http://forums.iis.net/post/1956461.aspx) that outlines a problem pretty similar to yours (it also outlines how they managed to fix it). Hopefully it helps you sort out the issue!

Comment: +1 Thanks for your input. This only fixes a symptom not the disease. Our Application Pools restart nightly regardless of the amount of memory used.

Comment: Did you see the part about the "Shutdown time limit"?

Comment: Ok, great. Where can I change that value? the web.config?

Comment: I got to it via the **Advanced Settings** in IIS Manager

Comment: I got to _that_ by clicking on **Application Pools** in IIS Manager then right-clicking on the one I wanted. It shows up in the **Process Model** section